# WebDriver is unable to perform click on an input element having onclick=function1() as an attribute

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Web driver 2.31 with Java.  It seems the web driver is unable to perform click action on an input element having `onclick()` attribute.

The input element I need to perform click action on is having the following attributes - `id` (which is a random generated number), `class`, `type=button`, `onclick`, `onmouseout`, `onmouseover`, `title` and `value`.

I'm able to fetch the values of `title` and `value` attributes which means that the web driver is able to recognize the input element but is not able to perform click action on it.

I have tried with the following:

1. `webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for the input")).click()`
2. `webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for the input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
3. `new Actions(webdriver).moveToElement(webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for the input"))).click().perform();`

None of the above options are working.

Comment: Post the html code of the application.

Comment: This is the html of the input element i need to perform click action.<input type="button" onclick="goNext()" onmouseout="this.className='buttonOff'" onmouseover="this.className='buttonOn'" class="buttonOff" title="Next &gt;" value="Next &gt;" id="956ee013-96d8-11e2-abcd-e1f3c648e1b7" name="956ee013-96d8-11e2-abcd-e1f3c648e1b7">

Comment: is it possible that selenium is trying to click before `goNext()` is loaded and defined? Also, depending on the css properties of `buttonOFf` and `buttonOn` there could be an issue with the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events?

Comment: Based on the brett statement place the mouse over that button before clicking on it.

Comment: Is driver throwing an exception? Are you sure the element is the element you want to perform click on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any exceptions from element.click()? It it enabled and visible? One of the problems we had was that WebDriver didn't handle position:static elements correctly, so during playback it would cover the button (and you won't see it on screenshot) and it would throw exception "Element is not clickable at point".

We had similar problem with  element and had following code that did work sometimes (but also not 100% of times):

```
element.click();
if("button".equals(tagName)) {
    if(element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed())
        element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

But the problem disappeared itself after upgrading WebDriver and we removed sendKeys(ENTER), also it was working fine in 2.29.0.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same problem in my project. **The issue was not to locate the element but the onClick() event was not firing.**
Then i found out that something else was there which stopped from the event to fire. I had used java script to enable the date picker box & did this,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('txtOriginDate').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");

WebElement originDateBox= driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("originDateBox")));
originDateBox.clear();
originDateBox.sendKeys("9-Dec-2014"); //Enter date
```

Developer designed this in such a way that if you don't use date picker to select date, a specific variable was not set. **Which eventually made the **onclick** event not to fire.

The date picker code was something like this,

```
var jsoncustdate = "";
var jsonorigindate = "";

function onSelectCalender( StrDt, obj ) 
{
    if ( !varReadonly ) {
    if ( $( "#txtCustDescisionDate" ).attr( "IsDisable" ) == "FALSE" ) 
    {
        if ( obj.id == "txtCustDescisionDate" ) 
        {
            custobjDt = new Date( obj.selectedYear, obj.selectedMonth,obj.selectedDay, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
            jsoncustdate = custobjDt.getTime();
            jsoncustdate = "\/Date(" + jsoncustdate + ")\/";
            DisabledBtnStage();
            //        $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", objDt);

        }
        if ( obj.id == "txtOriginDate" ) 
        {
            var objDt = new Date( obj.selectedYear, obj.selectedMonth,obj.selectedDay,0, 0,0,0 );
            jsonorigindate = objDt.getTime();
            jsonorigindate = "\/Date(" + jsonorigindate + ")\/";
            DisabledBtnStage();
            //        $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", objDt);
        }
    }
    elogCommon.CheckMandatory();
  }

}
```

I finally used date picker in normal way & the event fired smoothly.

I hope this answer will help . .cheers !!!